# Structure a json out of data from a table

Tags: java, jquery, json

I have a table with data like so:

```
a

b 

c

d

e

f

..so on till Z
```

now I need to load this into a JSON and I'm really really confused as to how it will be .

will it be

```
{"rec":{"character":"a"}, "rec":{"character":"b"}}
```

or should it all be within an array (this doesn't make sense to me) ?

I'm really new to JSON and would really appreciate some quick help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For a complicated table: The "correct" approach depends on what the data actually means. You could use arrays for the key-values:

```
{"a":[1,2,3], "b":[4,5,6], etc.}
```

However, it's often better to use sub-keys. For instance, say I have a database table like:

```
RECORD   FIRST  LAST    BIRTHYEAR
     1   Sam    Spade   1977
     2   Jane   Tarzan  1945
     3   Billy  Boinger 1984
```

To convert the whole table into JSON, I might do:

```
{
1: {
  "first":"Sam",
  "last":"Spade",
  "birthyear":1977
  },
2: {
  "first":"Jane",
  "last":"Tarzan",
  "birthyear":1945
  },
3: {
  "first":"Billy",
  "last":"Boinger",
  "birthyear":1984
  }
}
```

You can see how that is not only more readable, but it makes it easier to access precisely the data you need.

Answer (score 2):

If these are values from a select query, I would think you can do it using a [`JSONArray`](http://www.json.org/javadoc/org/json/JSONArray.html).  Its string structure would look like this:

```
["a","b","c",...,"x","y","z"]
```

It currently cannot be what you have listed, as your (top level) `JSONObject` contains two of the same key "rec".

Comment: so lets say i had 2 columns like:

a|1
b|2

then how would the JSON structure look?

Comment: @mblase75 , but thats saying that for the Key "a" , it has a value 1.

what happens in the case of > 2 columns ?

Comment: Then things get complicated. The "correct" approach depends on what the data actually means. You could use arrays for the key-values: `{"a":[1,2,3], "b":[4,5,6], etc.}`

Comment: Most interesting . Awesome . Let me make sense of it and get back if there are any hiccups ! :) 

Thanks!